# Gitkraken stuck in an infinite loop on startup after trying to merge branches

Tags: git, gitkraken

I use Gitkraken. I merge two branches by error and have almost 20000 files in conflict. From that moment, Git kraken is stuck in an infinite loop.

I saw several answer on Gitkraken stuck in loop on Stackoverflow or github, I tried to restart, refresh ... but doesn't work.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this a few times with GitKraken. Sometimes the best way to handle this is to use gitbash (command line).

1. Close GitKraken
2. In gitbash use use the following commands

   ```
   git merge --abort
   git reset --hard
   git merge <branch-you-want-merged-in-your-current-branch>
   ```
3. Then proceed to handle any merge conflicts

   ```
   git status
   ```

   Any files in red have merge conflicts - depending on the number of files, it may be safe to use GitKraken for this - or you may have to use a standard text editor.

If this fails to reset GitKraken properly, you may have to remove the settings folder located here

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\GitKraken

Or resinstall GitKraken